Reference for the solution of this optimization problem that shows up in linear discriminant analysis
I'm looking for a reference to the solution of trace-ratio linear discriminant analysis with an orthogonality constraint. Consider the following optimization problem where $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive semi-definite matrices.
\begin{cases}
\underset{V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}}{\text{maximize }} \frac{\text{tr}\left(V^TAV\right)}{\text{tr}\left(V^TBV\right)}, \\
\text{subject to } V^TV = I.
\end{cases}
I remember reading a paper that said that a general geometric method solving for $V$ didn't exist. However, the problem could be solved using an algebraic method with two steps:

Find $\lambda>0$ such that $\underset{V}{\text{max}}\,\, \text{tr}\left(V^TAV\right) - \lambda \text{tr}\left(V^TBV\right) = 0.$ (This can be done via binary search.)
Find $V$ using eigen-decomposition of the matrix $A - \lambda B$.

This was in the introduction section of a paper on orthogonal reformulations of LDA. I can't find this paper, OR the original paper that it referenced which first demonstrated this fact.
Any help on finding these references, or simply help on the proof of this result, would be greatly appreciated.
